# Empty nested structure

Tags: go

I was digging in AWS SDK source codes and came across with the following type declaration:

```
type Condition struct {
    _ struct{} `type:"structure"`

    // the rest of code is removed
}
```

Do anybody know purpose/explanation of this kind of embedding?

Comment: In addition to other uses, an underscored empty struct field can also be used (and _is_ used by the standard library in places) as a zero-size method of [blocking unkeyed literals](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/10/09/padding-is-hard).

Answer (score 1):

Its been used for code generation perposes. you can think of it like java which treats everything in it as an object.

example of using it is [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/c0defea9598061451cf5ffd452d2ffe3d91dbc5e/agent/gogenerate/awssdk.go#L54)

```
{{ $shapeList := ShapeListWithErrors $ }}
{{ range $_, $s := $shapeList }}
{{ if eq $s.Type "structure"}}{{ $s.GoCode }}{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```